# playing a url link instead of a .mp3 file in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, avfoundation

I have made a simple swift audio view using AVFoundation. the code works for downloaded files but I do not want the app size to be very large. is it possible if i can ply it from a URL link instead?

my code is

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import AVFAudio

struct AudioTest: View {
    
    @State var song1 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: song1 ? "pause.circle.fill": "play.circle.fill")
            .font(.system(size: 25))
            .padding(.trailing)
            .onTapGesture {
                playSound(sound: "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3", type: "mp3")
                song1.toggle()
                
                if song1{
                    
                    audioPlayer1?.play()
                } else {
                    audioPlayer1?.pause()
                    
                }
        }
    }
}

struct AudioTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AudioTest()
    }
}

var audioPlayer1: AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound1(sound: String, type:String){
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: type) {
        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            //audioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
            
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `AVPlayer` to stream resources from a URL like this. I'd also move the streaming/async logic into an `ObservableObject`:

```
class SoundManager : ObservableObject {
    var audioPlayer: AVPlayer?

    func playSound(sound: String){
        if let url = URL(string: sound) {
            self.audioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var song1 = false
    @StateObject private var soundManager = SoundManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: song1 ? "pause.circle.fill": "play.circle.fill")
            .font(.system(size: 25))
            .padding(.trailing)
            .onTapGesture {
                soundManager.playSound(sound: "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3")
                song1.toggle()
                
                if song1{
                    soundManager.audioPlayer?.play()
                } else {
                    soundManager.audioPlayer?.pause()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is important to keep reference in class (StateObject) otherwise AVPlayer gets deallocated and nothing plays.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `AVPlayer`**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var player: AVPlayer?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Play Audio") {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/audio.mp3") else { return }
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            self.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```